# How to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS while using Virtual Hosting in Tomcat

Tags: ssl, redirect, virtualhost, tomcat9

I need to configure my Tomcat 9 server to redirect http to https traffic.

I have tried:

1. Using a connector for the http port and having a redirectPort attribute pointing to the secure connector.
2. Including a security-constraint [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208796/redirect-http-to-httpsport-in-tomcat) at the bottom of the web.xml, which works for other Tomcat servers that are not using Virtual Hosting

Connector

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="443" />

<Connector 
        port="443"
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
        secure="true"
        scheme="https" 
        maxThreads="200" 
        SSLEnabled="true" 
        maxSpareThreads="75" 
        maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" 
        acceptCount="100"  
        enableLookups="false" 
        disableUploadTimeout="true"
        defaultSSLHostConfigName="example1.com">
                        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
                        <SSLHostConfig hostName="example1.com">
                                        <Certificate 
                                        certificateKeystoreFile="www_example1_com.jks"
                                        certificateKeystorePassword="…” />
                        </SSLHostConfig>
                        <SSLHostConfig hostName="example2.com">
                                        <Certificate 
                                        certificateKeystoreFile="www_example2_com.jks"
                                        certificateKeystorePassword="…” />
                        </SSLHostConfig>
        </Connector>
```

Security Constraint

```
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
   </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Host configuration in server.xml

```
      <!-- example1.com -->
      <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" 
               directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>

      <!-- example2.com -->
      <Host name="example2.com" appBase="website-webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" 
               directory="website-logs"
               prefix="website_access_log." 
               suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
```

- https://example2.com - Works
- https://www.example2.com - Works
- www.example2.com - Does not Work
- example2.com - Does not work

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 was not open to outside traffic on my server, so the redirect could never happen.  The http traffic was not getting to the server.

This was resolved by adding an inbound rule that allowed requests to reach port 80.