# Converting HTTP Request to HTTPS using security constraint. Port number in the URL giving an error

Tags: java, ssl, https

Added security constraint in web.xml to convert http request to https.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SessionTest</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
```

For example, http://example/demo/index.jsp is getting redirected to https://example:12311/demo/index.jsp.

When trying to access the application url after changes, it gives me 'This site can’t be reached'.

If I try to remove the port number from url, it works fine. I want it get redirected to https without any portnumber mentioned in URL. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: you should configure your connector as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33274112/175554